# Unable to show the graphs on the same row in Dash in Python

Tags: python, css, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am unable to show the graphs in the same rows.

I would like to show the graphs one side to the other. I tried the inline-block as style formatting, but I do not want to apply that. Rather, I want to change the external style CSS to support my expected change. The Plotly site documentation suggests using a subplot or a mixed subplot, but I am not able to fruitfully apply it. How can I do it?

Code:

```python
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

data = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
data.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)

# external_stylesheets =
#  [
#     {
#         "href": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?"
#         "family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap",
#         "rel": "stylesheet",
#     },
# ]`


external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.title = "Avocado Analytics: Understand Your Avocados!"

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.P(children="", className="header-emoji"),
                html.H1(
                    children="Avocado Analytics", className="header-title"
                ),
                html.P(
                    children="Analyze the behavior of avocado prices"
                    " and the number of avocados sold in the US"
                    " between 2015 and 2018",
                    className="header-description",
                ),
            ],
            className="header",
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Region", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="region-filter",
                            options=[
                                {"label": region, "value": region}
                                for region in np.sort(data.region.unique())
                            ],
                            value="Albany",
                            clearable=False,
                            className="dropdown",
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Type", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="type-filter",
                            options=[
                                {"label": avocado_type, "value": avocado_type}
                                for avocado_type in data.type.unique()
                            ],
                            value="organic",
                            clearable=False,
                            searchable=False,
                            className="dropdown",
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(
                            children="Date Range",
                            className="menu-title"
                            ),
                        dcc.DatePickerRange(
                            id="date-range",
                            min_date_allowed=data.Date.min().date(),
                            max_date_allowed=data.Date.max().date(),
                            start_date=data.Date.min().date(),
                            end_date=data.Date.max().date(),
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(
                        id="price-chart", config={"displayModeBar": False},
                        style={'display': 'block'}
                        # style={'display': 'inlineBlock'}
                    ),
                    className="card",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(
                        id="volume-chart", config={"displayModeBar": False},
                        style={'display': 'block'}
                        # style={'display': 'inlineBlock'}
                    ),
                    className="card",
                ),
            ],
            className="wrapper",
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("price-chart", "figure"), Output("volume-chart", "figure")],
    [
        Input("region-filter", "value"),
        Input("type-filter", "value"),
        Input("date-range", "start_date"),
        Input("date-range", "end_date"),
    ],
)
def update_charts(region, avocado_type, start_date, end_date):
    mask = (
        (data.region == region)
        & (data.type == avocado_type)
        & (data.Date >= start_date)
        & (data.Date <= end_date)
    )
    filtered_data = data.loc[mask, :]
    price_chart_figure = {
        "data": [
            {
                "x": filtered_data["Date"],
                "y": filtered_data["AveragePrice"],
                "type": "barstack",
                "hovertemplate": "$%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>",
            },
        ],
        "layout": {
            "title": {
                "text": "Average Price of Avocados",
                "x": 0.05,
                "xanchor": "left",
            },
            "xaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
            "yaxis": {"tickprefix": "$", "fixedrange": True},
            "colorway": ["#17B897"],
        },
    }

    volume_chart_figure = {
        "data": [
            {
                "x": filtered_data["Date"],
                "y": filtered_data["Total Volume"],
                "type": "lines",
            },
        ],
        "layout": {
            "title": {"text": "Avocados Sold", "x": 0.05, "xanchor": "left"},
            "xaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
            "yaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
            "colorway": ["#E12D39"],
        },
    }
    return price_chart_figure, volume_chart_figure


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am using external CSS file for styling and want to make changes in that:

CSS file content:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", calibri;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #38543d;
}

.header {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 288px;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; */
}

.header-emoji {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-title {
    color: #58adab;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-description {
    color: #68d97c;
    margin: 4px auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 384px;
}

.wrapper {

    /* margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto; */
    max-width: 400px;

    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

.card {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* width: 49% */
    /* margin-bottom: 24px; */
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.menu {
    height: 112px;
    width: 912px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin: -80px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.Select-control {
    width: 256px;
    height: 48px;
}

.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value, .Select-placeholder {
    line-height: 48px;
}

.Select--multi .Select-value-label {
    line-height: 32px;
}

.menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #079A82;
}

.row {
   display: inlineblock;
}
```

Reference code:

https://realpython.com/python-dash/

[Code reference](https://realpython.com/python-dash/)